# Compare files in a folder from a previous release

Tags: azure-devops

We have a task/job during our release pipeline that we would like to skip in the event that files haven't changed in a particular folder in our repo. I am able to get a powershell script task to change a variable to skip the following task properly, but I don't know how I can do the actual comparison to determine whether to skip or not.

How can I compare changes via git or some other way to see if files have changed in a particular folder since the last release? Is it possible to compare the current artifact to the last deployed artifact in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to compare the current artifact to the last deployed artifact in some way?

Yes. We can add a PowerShell task and run Rest APIs to compare the artifacts and get the changes files.

Here is an PowerShell example:

```
$token = "$(PAT)"

$url=" https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=releasedefinitionid&deploymentStatus=succeeded&definitionEnvironmentId=releasedefinitionenvironmentid&api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

echo $response.value[0].release.id

$lastreleaseid = $response.value[0].release.id

$url1 ="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_apis/Release/releases/$(RELEASE.RELEASEID)/changes?baseReleaseId=$($lastreleaseid)&%24top=2500&artifactAlias=Artifacts Alias name&api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
$count = 0

Foreach ($commitid in $response1.value.id)
{
  echo $commitid

  $url2 = "https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/_apis/git/repositories/RepoId/commits/$($commitid)/changes?api-version=7.0"
  $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

  Foreach ($changefile in $response2.changes)
  {
     $filepath= $changefile.item.path

     if($filepath -like '/test*')
     {
        $count = $count + 1
     }

  }
}

echo $count

if($count -gt 0 )
{
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=one]secondValue"
}
```

**Explanation:**

Step1: We can use the Rest API:[Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to get the last successful Release of the Release environmen.

Step2: We can use the following Rest API to get the commits between two release.

```
Get https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_apis/Release/releases/currentreleaseid/changes?baseReleaseId=comparereleaseid&%24top=2500&artifactAlias=Artifacts Alias name&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

Step3: We can get the changed files of the commits via the Rest API: [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

Finally, we can set the Pipeline variable based on the result of the API response.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Ok wow so it's all through the rest api. That's great. Do you know if the info needed for the api call is easily found in ADO somewhere? The `releaseDefinitionId`, `definitionEnvironmentId`, etc.?

Comment: YES. this is very easy to find in ADO. You can edit the release pipeline and select the stage. Then you can check the URL.